# A custom view for VNDocumentCameraViewController

Tags: ios, swift, iphone

I want to customize the view of VNDocumentCameraViewController which I used it from VisionKit, IS it possible?

Here it is :
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/visionkit/vndocumentcameraviewcontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible yet. may be possible in future versions.